# Consecutive Select statement in SQlite3 with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, select, sqlite

I'm developing an automatic internet form filler software using Python 3 and Sqlite3.
Here my problem and my question:
how I can choose a value from the database table (for example: a Surname) and insert it into "send_keys(here_the_value)" to fill my internet form?
I know something like this (for example):

```
cursor.execute("""
select name, surname, city from people
""")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    name, surname, city = row
    .....send_keys(surname)
```

these are definitely too much lines! When you fill a form, you need to process a lot of consecutive values, as you know.

Using Shelve (which is not a database, but I used it the same), you can write simply, for example:

surname.send_keys(database.contact[customer]["Surname"])

in fact the value 'Surname' is stored in database.contact[customer]["Surname"]

So, with SQlite3, it exists a simple way like last one, using ONE LINE, instead of using first coding?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you write a function that does what you want?

Comment: good idea, but I hope there was a statement just ready, if not, your answer is the only possibility.

Comment: Have you a ready function for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

an example:

```
def t1_values(a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,c1,d1):
    cursor.execute("""
    select %s,%s,%s,%s FROM %s
    WHERE %s=?
    """%(a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,c1),(d1))

    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        a1,a2,a3,a4=row
        print(a1,a2,a3,a4)

t1_values('id','nome','cognome','data_nascita','t1','id','3')
```